# How to create multiple indices with imakeidx?

Tags: indexing, subdividing, imakeidx

I want to create two indices with the package imakeidx, using the splitindex option:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=foo,title=Test]

\begin{document}
Test1\index{Test1}
Test2\index[foo]{Test2}
\newpage
Test3\index{Test3}
Test4\index[foo]{Test4}

\printindex
\printindex[foo]
\end{document}
```

The result isan error message `Input index file foo-foo.idx not found`. Which seems quite irrtating, since `\jobname` is not `foo`.

If I omit the `splitindex` option, the indices are created, but both now have the name `Test` and both include all indexes, regardless of the option to the `\index`-command.

I use pdfLaTeX version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) and version 1.2b of imakeidx.

Comment: This seems to create two indexes for me titles: `Index` and `Test`.

Comment: I apologize. Version 1.2 has introduced severe bugs. A fix is under work.

Comment: The fixed version is on its way to CTAN. Happily the fix was not so difficult. I apologize again. You can download the fixed version also from http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/imakeidx.sty

Comment: The fixed version (1.2d) of `imakeidx` has been [included in TeX Live](http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=date&revision=27920). It should be available for updating with `tlmgr` in a few hours (depending on the server one uses for updates).