# How create multiple indices with imakeidx?

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

The following source file was shown in: [How to create multiple indices with imakeidx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75459/how-to-create-multiple-indices-with-imakeidx)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=foo,title=Test]

\begin{document}
Test1\index{Test1}
Test2\index[foo]{Test2}
\newpage
Test3\index{Test3}
Test4\index[foo]{Test4}

\printindex
\printindex[foo]
\end{document}
```

That question was closed because, allegedly, an error in `imakeidx` was fixed.

However, when I process that source file by running `pdflatex` (twice, to be sure), then `makeindex`, and finally `pdflatex` again, I get no index whatsoever. In fact, there is a single `.ind` file, and that file is empty.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Remove the `splitindex` option or run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get a warning:

```
Package imakeidx Warning: Remember to run (pdf)latex again after calling
(imakeidx)                `splitindex' and processing the indices.
```

which tells you exactly what you need to do.

Alternatively, run `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option.

Explanation: `splitindex` is not in the “list of safe programs” allowed to be called from the restricted shell escape.

Another possibility, with just two indices, is to remove the `splitindex` option.